# Problem in merging two stack-exchange accounts

Tags: discussion, merge-accounts, user-profile

I have accidentally created two math-stack exchange accounts namely https://math.stackexchange.com/users/186473/learnmore and https://math.stackexchange.com/users/294365/amartya .

It was created because I had lost login details of one account.

I tried to merge them by going to the contact forum and then filling the form under the section "Merge user profiles"

But I failed to do it.

Every time I did it,there came a message that you will receive a e-mail shortly but none received.

What should I do now?Should I leave it as it is or I have any option available?Please help.

Comment: There was a company meet-up this week, so the support tasks fell behind a bit. I'd suggest you wait a bit more. If you don't get an email some time next week, re-raise the issue.

Comment: Thank you @DanielFischer;I shall do as suggested